# What to use to fill holes in floor tile in kitchen

Tags: flooring, kitchens, tile, hole

We just did a final walkthrough for a house we should close on in a few days.  The kitchen has tile flooring.  There are some holes in several of the tiles.  The holes aren't too deep, maybe 1/4 to 1/2 inch deep.  Luckily no cracks in the tile from whatever created the hole.  I was wondering what can we use to fill in the holes.

The things I googled all appear to be for bathroom/shower tiles (can post a link if needed) and not kitchen floor tiles.  I don't want to buy the wrong thing because I mis-interpreted what I'm reading/seeing.  Thanks.

EDIT: Here's a couple photos.
[image: hole1]
[image: hole2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, a travertine repair kit is the right choice here. Those depressions are normal in travertine tile. High-end retail tiles come with those holes already repaired. The filling medium hardens and all of the tiles and grout should be sealed afterward to eliminate staining. These are my preferred sealer choices:

[image: sealer's choice]  [image: stone sealer]

Answer (score 3):

Are these screw holes? What material is the tile? A picture would be helpful too.

But generally speaking, you can use anything that won't look ridiculous. The tile should be well supported aside from the little hole, so there isn't a structural concern. There isn't a significant water infiltration concern on a kitchen floor. So it's really just about what will blend visually:

- Grout will adhere well and cure hard. Probably the best choice for blending with a stone tile.
- Caulk is easy to apply. Won't be as durable as grout but probably OK in the middle of a tile. If you're looking to match a glossy surface (like a white porcelain) this is a good choice. I'd recommend using a silicone or polyurethane based caulk here; latex/acrylic painter's caulk wouldn't stand up to much foot traffic.
- For the most durable but most expensive and difficult fix, go for a color-matched epoxy. This is the sort of thing countertop installers use at joints, and can be gotten or mixed in a big range of colors.

If you are seeing a caulk that's a decent color match, I'd probably start there. It'll run you like $5-10 a tube and if it sucks you can scrape it out and try something else. I wouldn't worry about kitchen/bathroom/whatever type, as these differences mostly have to do with microbial resistance additives and other stuff that isn't really significant if you're not caulking around a shower or sink.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I attached the photos.  I think the tiles are made out of stone.  The tiles are on the floor and I found/noticed more holes than earlier.  I hope we don't have to rip out all the tiles in the kitchen.  =(

Comment: Grout, either sanded or unsanded is not the right choice. Unsanded won't cure properly because of area/depth, wrong finish, it won't match. Sanded is wrong finish and won't cure properly w/o polymer additive. I hope you went with the kit.

Answer (score 1):

So a friend told me to use something called a Travertine Repair Kit [(link to Amazon)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FY3XO8I).  It seems to work.  I'll find out how hard it is when it dries and take photos to show the after.

Comment: Custom Building Products are excellent and they have great customer service.